# convert from Color to brush

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I convert a `Color` to a `Brush` in C#?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

This is for `Color` to `Brush`....

you can't convert it, you have to make a new brush....

```
SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush( myColor );
```

now, if you need it in XAML, you COULD make a custom value converter and use that in a binding

Comment: For backward compatibility, it would be better to use `SolidBrush` (`System.Drawing`), which is available since .NET Framework 1.1, instead of `SolidColorBrush` (`System.Windows.Media`), available starting from .NET Framework 3.0.

Comment: SolidColorBrush doesnt work in my C# winforms .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 app & Visual Studio's suggestion was installation of some NuGet packages.  SolidBrush works. Thanx @BillyJoe

Answer (score 40):

```
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

---

The other way around:

```
if (brush is SolidColorBrush colorBrush)
    Color color = colorBrush.Color;
```

Or something like that.

Point being not all brushes are colors but you could turn all colors into a (SolidColor)Brush.

Comment: Color to Brush!

Comment: @raiserle: For your information, the question content used to be `I want to convert from Brush to Color in c#` while the title was the other way around.

Comment: I had to use `new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0026FF"));` because `SolidColorBrush` is not happy with a Color parameter, it wants a media.Color as parameter

Comment: @GuidoG You could also use split it into the individual hex values and use  `Color.FromArgb(0x00, 0x26, 0xFF)`.

Answer (score 32):

```
SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush( Color.FromArgb(255,255,139,0) )
```

Answer (score 21):

you can use this:

```
new SolidBrush(color)
```

where color is something like this:

```
Color.Red
```

or

```
Color.FromArgb(36,97,121))
```

or ...

Comment: For backward compatibility, this answer is better, because `SolidBrush` (`System.Drawing`) is available since .NET Framework 1.1, while `SolidColorBrush` (`System.Windows.Media`) is available starting from .NET Framework 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Easiest way,  No Helpers, No Converters, No weird Media references. Just 1 line:

```
System.Drawing.Brush _Brush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(this.ForeColor.R, this.ForeColor.G, this.ForeColor.B));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be working with a application which has a mix of Windows Forms and WPF you might have the additional complication of trying to convert a System.Drawing.Color to a System.Windows.Media.Color.
I'm not sure if there is an easier way to do this, but I did it this way:

```
System.Drawing.Color MyColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
System.Windows.Media.Color = ConvertColorType(MyColor);

System.Windows.Media.Color ConvertColorType(System.Drawing.Color color)
{
  byte AVal = color.A;
  byte RVal = color.R;
  byte GVal = color.G;
  byte BVal = color.B;

  return System.Media.Color.FromArgb(AVal, RVal, GVal, BVal);
}
```

Then you can use one of the techniques mentioned previously to convert to a Brush.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue before, here is my class which solved color conversions
Use it and enjoy :

Here U go, Use my Class to Multi Color Conversion

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Media;
using SDColor = System.Drawing.Color;
using SWMColor = System.Windows.Media.Color;
using SWMBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brush;

//Developed by امین امیری دربان
namespace APREndUser.CodeAssist
{
    public static class ColorHelper
    {
        public static SWMColor ToSWMColor(SDColor color) => SWMColor.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
        public static SDColor ToSDColor(SWMColor color) => SDColor.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
        public static SWMBrush ToSWMBrush(SDColor color) => (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(ToHexColor(color)));
        public static string ToHexColor(SDColor c) => "#" + c.R.ToString("X2") + c.G.ToString("X2") + c.B.ToString("X2");
        public static string ToRGBColor(SDColor c) => "RGB(" + c.R.ToString() + "," + c.G.ToString() + "," + c.B.ToString() + ")";
        public static Tuple<SDColor, SDColor> GetColorFromRYGGradient(double percentage)
        {
            var red = (percentage > 50 ? 1 - 2 * (percentage - 50) / 100.0 : 1.0) * 255;
            var green = (percentage > 50 ? 1.0 : 2 * percentage / 100.0) * 255;
            var blue = 0.0;
            SDColor result1 = SDColor.FromArgb((int)red, (int)green, (int)blue);
            SDColor result2 = SDColor.FromArgb((int)green, (int)red, (int)blue);
            return new Tuple<SDColor, SDColor>(result1, result2);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's often sufficient to use sibling's or parent's brush for the purpose, and that's easily available in wpf via retrieving their Foreground or Background property.

ref: [Control.Background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background(v=vs.110).aspx)