# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Color' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush'

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ComboBox that has a list of colors, and I want to use the color selected to fill a rectangle so I did this:

```
var alwan = typeof(Colors).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties;
            foreach (var item in alwan)
            {
                x.Add(item);
            }
            CbForColors.ItemsSource = x;
            CbForColors_Copy.ItemsSource = x;

private void CbForColors_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var color = CbForColors.SelectedItem as PropertyInfo;
        //var color2 = color.GetMethod;
        //var color3 = color2.Invoke(color,null);
        Rect_Sample.Fill = (Color)color.GetValue(null);       
}
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`Windows.UI.Color`' to '`Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush`'

The commented lines I get the `argb` for the color, ie. `#FFA07FF0` (something like that). What's wrong with what is already implemented and how can I make a color from this `argb`? Should I turn it into a string and then turn each 2 characters into an int and put them in a new color a,r,g,b?

Comment: I believe this is a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641078/convert-from-color-to-brush

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need to use a SolidColorBrush:

```
 Rect_Sample.Fill = new SolidColorBrush( (Color)color.GetValue(null));
```

Comment: wow ty that was actually pretty obvious i guess i should take a break for now :D

Comment: @AmgadSerry, if that's what you were looking for, mark it as answer.