# Button foreground - how to easily obtain the color?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, colors

I created a brush to assign a color the the button foreground. But I cannot figure out to retrieve the color back?
I find a few solutions but there were very complicated.

I set the button foreground color to be BLACK.

Now I need a code that, provided with a button, retrieve the color and returns BLACK (in this example).

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: How do you access the foreground? Programmatically? Through bindings? Controls do not store their previous states, so you'll have to either store the original values or use WPF triggers, that automate the reversal process.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. I set the color of the button foreground to be black (using a brush). Now I want to obtain the color - BLACK.

Comment: Do you mean that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641078/convert-from-color-to-brush it shows the converting between brush and color and visa verca

Comment: I tried that but it is not a SolicColorBrush.

Comment: If it is not the SolidColorBrush, then what is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the current color of your element you can simply assign a new Color variable from the button like this:

```
Color getColor;
getColor = button1.ForeColor;
Console.WriteLine(getColor); /* To print the retrned color in the debug console */
```